# Calculate age (with decimal places) in R

Tags: r, date

I have two sets of dates

```
Testday<-as.Date(c("2015-06-25", "2015-06-25","2015-06-25"))
DOB<-as.Date(c("2012-03-15", "2004-04-21","2014-07-25"))
```

I want to calculate the age, correct to 2 decimal places.

On `Excel`, I would simply do this:
 `(Testday - DOB)/365.25`

and obtain these ages: `3.28, 11.18, 0.92`

Is there anyway I could perform this on `R` too?

Comment: Do the same in R: `round((Testday - DOB)/365.25, 2)`.

Comment: Hmm so what exactly didn't work with your code? The `round` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this OK?

```
round(as.numeric((Testday - DOB) / 365.25), 2)
#[1]  3.28 11.18  0.92
```