# I want to calculate a persons age at a certain date an present it as a separate variable

Tags: r

Anyone knows how to calculate AGE as showed below?

```
       DATE  BIRTHDATE      AGE
1 2009-10-03 1978-01-20 31 years
```

Or in this case?

```
      DATE  BIRTHDATE      AGE
1 2009-10-03 20.01.1978 31 years
```

Best regards, 
H

Comment: `as.integer((as.Date("2009-10-03") - as.Date("1978-01-20")) / 365)` gives 31. (This can be done on whole columns, so perhaps `df$AGE <- as.integer((df$DATE - df$BIRTHDATE) / 365)` assuming that each column is already a `Date` object.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient and accurate age calculation (in years, months, or weeks) in R given birth date and an arbitrary date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126726/efficient-and-accurate-age-calculation-in-years-months-or-weeks-in-r-given-b)

Comment: Thanks. Should have searched before asking.. Sry