# How to calculate the mean age from the data stated as 2 digit years in R

Tags: r, datetime, mean

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
birthday <- c(12, 23, 2, 20)
birthmonth <- c(8, 10, 3, 9)
birthyear <- c(79, 62, 66, 83)
mydf <- data.frame(ID, birthday, birthmonth, birthyear)
mydf
  ID birthday birthmonth birthyear
1  A       12          8        79
2  B       23         10        62
3  C        2          3        66
4  D       20          9        83
```

So, as you can see birth years are stated as 2 digits, and month, day, and year information are on different columns.
In such a data frame, how can I calculate mean age for my sample?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lubridate`'s `make_date()` to turn the individual columns into a date column and then calculate the age. I have shown here how you could take care of the missing `19`/`20` in `birthyear`, but you might need to tweak it for your data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydf |> 
    mutate(date = make_date(if_else(birthyear > 21, birthyear+1900, birthyear), birthmonth, birthday),
           age  = as.period(interval(date, today()))$year
    )
```

Output:

```r
  ID birthday birthmonth birthyear       date age
1  A       12          8        79 1979-08-12  43
2  B       23         10        62 1962-10-23  59
3  C        2          3        66 1966-03-02  56
4  D       20          9        83 1983-09-20  38
```

And to get the `mean` age with `summarise`:

```r
mydf |> 
    mutate(date = make_date(if_else(birthyear > 21, birthyear+1900, birthyear), birthmonth, birthday),
           age  = as.period(interval(date, today()))$year
    ) |>
    summarise(mean_age = mean(age))
```

Output:

```r
  mean_age
1       49
```

**Update:** It can be non-trivial to get the right age calculation (fast), check e.g. [Efficient and accurate age calculation (in years, months, or weeks) in R given birth date and an arbitrary date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126726/efficient-and-accurate-age-calculation-in-years-months-or-weeks-in-r-given-b)

Comment: This is what happened:
I don't know why my error has changed to this --> in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `date =
  make_date(...)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must be a double vector,
  not an integer vector.

and then I changed if_else to ifelse and wrote the code like this: 

mydf <- mydf |> 
    mutate(date = make_date(ifelse(birthyear > 21, birthyear+1900, birthyear), birthmonth, birthday),
           age  = as.period(interval(date, today()))$year
    )

and then it worked. I don't know the reason behind it but anyway I wanted to share. Thank you!

Comment: It has to do with `birthyear` not being a numeric type. You might want to add `mutate(birthyear = as.numeric(birthyear)` to be sure not to get unexpected behaviour.